# "warning: implicit declaration of function 'strdup'" when configuring binutils

Tags: c, gcc, configure, toolchain, binutils

```
../../../binutils-2.37/bfd/doc/chew.c:1349:32: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘strdup’; did you mean ‘strcmp’? [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
 1349 |   dict_type *new_d = newentry (strdup (name));
      |                                ^~~~~~
      |                                strcmp
../../../binutils-2.37/bfd/doc/chew.c:1349:32: warning: passing argument 1 of ‘newentry’ makes pointer from integer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]
 1349 |   dict_type *new_d = newentry (strdup (name));
      |                                ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
      |                                |
      |                                int
../../../binutils-2.37/bfd/doc/chew.c:1315:12: note: expected ‘char *’ but argument is of type ‘int’
 1315 |      char *word;
      |            ^~~~
```

These are the errors I get when configuring binutils, I am quite confused by this because usually warnings don't automatically stop the process.
Let me know if I should send the full log.

Comment: For clarification, `string.h` is included in `chew.c`.

Comment: What OS/version are you building on? The [Linux `strdup()` man page](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strdup.3.html) lists both `_XOPEN_SOURCE >= 500` and `_POSIX_C_SOURCE >= 200809L` as prerequisite definitions for declaring `strdup()`.  What are the arguments passed to `gcc`?

Comment: Note in this case you're lucky the build stopped - you would have gotten something broken somewhere, assuming you're compiling 64-bit binaries.  Every use of `strdup()` in the code would result in the 64-bit `char *` pointer `strdup()` actually returns getting truncated to a 32-bit `int` value that's the assumed return value from a function without a prototype.

Comment: I'm on WSL Ubuntu and using GCC 11.2.0, and these are the arguments that configure used `-o chw$$ -std=c99 -g \
    -I.. -I../../../binutils-2.37/bfd/doc/.. -I../../../binutils-2.37/bfd/doc/../../include -I../../../binutils-2.37/bfd/doc/../../intl -I../../intl ../../../binutils-2.37/bfd/doc/chew.c; \
/bin/bash ../../../binutils-2.37/bfd/doc/../../move-if-change \
  chw$$ chew; \
touch chew.stamp`

Comment: Now that I think about it, I think it might be `-std=c99` that's causing the error... but I'm not sure.

Comment: *I'm on WSL Ubuntu*  `strdup()` might not be available.  Offhand, I don't know where to look to find out, though.

Comment: @Andrew Henle WSL2 Ubuntu is a true VM running Linux. gcc is exactly the same you'd find on a non-WSL Ubuntu system.  WSL1 is slightly different, but close enough. `strdup` is found in both.

Comment: BTW: all warnings containing the word `implicit` should always be considered a errors.

Comment: Do you think that `-std=c99` would be the error?